# What is the difference between comparing for equality with variations of & and * on the arguments?

Tags: pointers, rust

I wrote the following function:

```
fn test() {
    let xs = [b"AAA", b"BBB"];
    let buf = b"AAA";
    println!("{:?}", xs.iter().find(|&x| &x == &&buf));
}
```

This works, but I'm confused because these also work:

- `println!("{:?}", xs.iter().find(|&x| x == &buf));`
- `println!("{:?}", xs.iter().find(|&x| *x == buf));`

What is the difference between these variations? `*` and `&` certainly seem to behave very differently from the same in C. What nuance of these operators do I need to understand to understand the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant difference is in the behavior of the equality operator. The semantics of `x == y` and `&x == &y` are the same: they compare `x` and `y`.

`&x == &y` desugars to [`PartialEq::eq(&&x, &&y)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#tymethod.eq). `PartialEq` in turn has the blanket implementation

```
impl<'a, 'b, A, B> PartialEq<&'b B> for &'a A
where
    A: PartialEq<B> + ?Sized,
    B: ?Sized,
```

It reads "If values of types `A` and `B` can be compared for equality (`where A: PartialEq<B>`), then we provide an implementation for comparison of values of types `&A` and `&B` (`impl PartialEq<&B> for &A`)." I'm omitting the lifetimes for brevity.

The implementation is [straightforward](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/51b47dc4a1af3260738aa7c5d4e31e8d77c0c0b6/src/libcore/cmp.rs#L912), it compares the dereferenced values.

```
fn eq(&self, other: & &'b B) -> bool { 
    PartialEq::eq(*self, *other) 
}
```

thus `PartialEq::eq(&&x, &&y)` calls `PartialEq::eq(*&&x, *&&y)`, which is the same as `PartialEq::eq(&x, &y)` or `x == y`.